# How to get image format using skimage?

Tags: image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('abc.jpg')
print(im.format) //output: JPEG
```

How can I write the above code using skimage?

I tried:

```
import skimage
from PIL import Image
im = skimage.io.imread('abc.jpg')
print(Image.fromarray(im).format)
```

Did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that with `skimage`.

When you load an image with PIL like this:

```
im = Image.open(path)
```

it returns a `PIL Image` object which stores the width, height, colourspace, palette and EXIF data.

When you load an image with `skimage` it just returns a pure Numpy array corresponding to the pixel colours so there is no place to store the format or anything else.